# Google Drive API get AppProperties with API Key

Tags: google-drive-api, share, google-api-nodejs-client

## Question:

Is it possible to access the **appProperties** field in a Google Drive document via an unauthenticated user (i.e., via API Key or other method rather than Oauth)?

## Background:

I have an app that works as a live document editor. It authenticates users via OAuth and allows them to save those documents to their google drive, and later re-open them in my app (google file ids are saved in my database and will load the document text into my app). Create()-ing and Get()-ing these files works fine as long as the user is signed in, and I have the "appProperties" field storing a couple of additional key metadata items.

As a next step, I would like to allow users to mark a document as "public view", and provide read-only access to their file, even for non-logged-in users. In my head, the flow would work as follows:

1. User_A authenticates with OAuth and creates a document, saved to their google drive.
2. User_A presses a button in my app, which sets the google document to a public sharing mode?
3. App generates a "viewer" link that User_A can share with his friends.
4. User_B does not have a Google account, but visits the "viewer link", and my app looks up the appropriate google document (using API key? since User_B is not logged in)
5. Document is loaded into my app for viewing.

This seems to mostly work; I can read the file metadata just fine using the API key, and even get the file contents. **Side Note:** Why do we need the API Key at all, given the quote on the [google drive api page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get): "Note: Authorization ***optional***."

However, the "appProperties" field always returns empty when using the API key!

**Edit:** After further searching I am just more confused. The closest answer I could find was from this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56546666/6227520) here on stackoverflow:

> It's very simple. **appPropperties** is a **private** field and is available **only** to the application that added it.

Based on this, it seems Google Drive is treating requests from my app API Key and requests from OAuth users on my app as *two separate apps*?

Further, I would eventually like to allow users to collaborate on a single document, owned by one user. So instead of just providing a read-only "view" link, they could generate an "editor invitation" link that would allow an authenticated user (User_B gets a google account now) to be added as an authorized collaborator (but not simultaneous editing) on the original (User_A's) document. Is that even possible?

Note I am using the Node.js google api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This might be a bug:

`appProperties` are app-specific properties attached to a file. Any call from this app should be able to access them. Therefore, I think calls from this app using an API key should be able to retrieve these properties.

I could reproduce this behaviour: `appProperties` are populated when using OAuth, but not when using an API key, even though both are created from the same GCP project.

#### I filed a bug:

After researching this issue, I think this might be a bug. Therefore, I decided to file a bug on Issue Tracker:

- [appProperties are not populated when accessing a public File using an API key](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169834768)

To anyone affected by this, I'd suggest to click the top-left star in order to keep track of this and to help prioritizing it.

#### Reference:

- [Add custom file properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/properties)

Comment: Thanks for trying to reproduce the behavior. Once Google responds to your bug report I will mark this as the answer if it is indeed a bug.

Comment: @TrevorBuckner You're welcome. This report has already been forwarded internally.